# Youtube API doesn't work--Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, youtube

Here is my code: I am trying to get the current time of youtube when it runs. However, it always reminds me error messages: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". It confuses me a lot. Because I have already defined player ahead. Why the function couldn't be used? Beside getCurrentTime method, I also test other methods, like getVolume(), it also comes across same error.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head> 
  <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
  <title>THis is YOutube API testing </title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
   <iframe id="video" width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/02GcUZ6hgzo" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>

  <script>
  //import YouTube API script
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  //create the YouTube Player
  var player;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    console.log("API  is Ready");
    player = new YT.Player("video", { 
    events : {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady(),
      'onStateChange': onStateChangeEvent()
      } 
    });
  }
  function onPlayerReady() {
    console.log("My plaer is onReady" );

  }
  function onStateChangeEvent(){
    setInterval(function(){
       var time = player.getCurrentTime();
      //var volume = player.getVolume();
      console.log("Get Current Time: " + time);
    },1000); 

  }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error Message in picture:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just figured it out. It is because I didn't enable the javascript in my URL.

Here is the description on [Google Official Docs.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingStarted)

```
Enabling the JavaScript API for a chromeless player

If your application is using a chromeless player, use the following URL to load the player in your application and enable JavaScript API handlers in the player. You can then build your own custom player controls using JavaScript:

http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1&version=3
Enabling the JavaScript API for an embedded player

Use the following URL to load an embedded video player. In the URL, replace the string VIDEO_ID with the 11-character YouTube video ID that identifies the video that the player will show.

http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&enablejsapi=1
```

Comment: That is great to hear. Go ahead and have this as the answer so others will see what the solution was

Comment: This is really good for other people to know. Youtube's documentation for its new iframe API (https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) does not explicitly say to include that enablejsapi=1 parameter. Only the deprecated API docs say it! If you're like me, and you're using the new iframe API, and you're also manually putting the iframe in your html instead of generating it through the API the way they suggest, you need to include this parameter!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is going on. When I put it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pertrai1/41ajdbkb/), it seems to be working. Could you explain more that I possibly am missing:

```
Don't know why I have to add code if I don't see any problems with the code in question?
```

Comment: I just went into JSFiddle you created, but I don't see it show anything on console. Normally, it should invoke onready event, right?